# Audio alignment (same sentence with different speakers)

Tags: python, audio, alignment, mfcc, dtw

I am super new to audio processing. I have one reference audio file and several other audio recordings (same sentence spoken by different speakers - differ in dialect and duration) and I want to align the all the audio files to the one audio reference file with the least warping. I tried using MFCC and Chroma features (python/librosa) but I don't know what to do next. I was reading about DTW (Dynamic Time Warping) for alignment, would that work? Is there an example/open source project or audio tool which already does this? It seems to be a solved problem but I couldn't find it. Please help.

I was following read this - 
https://librosa.github.io/librosa_gallery/auto_examples/plot_music_sync.html but how do I save back the aligned audio in time domain?

This seems related - [Dynamic time warping with python (final mapping)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36152229/dynamic-time-warping-with-python-final-mapping/46801647?noredirect=1#comment80550012_46801647)

Comment: This falls in the realm of signal processing , hence question may be better suited to be posted at https://dsp.stackexchange.com/ rather here which is more related to coding.

Comment: Have you solved your problem? I have the same one. What did you do?